# nested ssh -t -t not providing $PS1

Tags: bash, ssh, pipe, environment-variables, tty

I am trying to run a nested ssh -t -t but it won't provide me the environment variables when working with `cat` and `echo`.

```
#!/bin/bash

pass="password\n"
bla="cat <(echo -e '$pass') - | sudo -S su -"
ssh -t -t -t -t jumpserver "ssh -t -t -t -t server \"$bla\" "
```

I get an output without any variables taken into consideration. (e.g. PS1 does not get shown but commands work fine) The problem is related to `cat <(echo -e '$pass') -` but this was the way to keep `echo` alive after providing the password for `sudo`.

How can i achieve this and get environment variables to get a proper output?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. The `-tt` is enough. Using more `-t` does not add any more effect and just makes an impression that you have no idea what are you doing.
2. What is the point of `cat <(echo -e)` construction? Writing just `echo` would result in the same, isn't it?
3. Why to use `sudo su`? `sudo` already does all you need, isn't it?

So how can it look in some fashionable manner?

```
pass="password\n"
bla="echo '$pass' | sudo -Si"
ssh -tt jumpserver "ssh -tt server \"$bla\""
```

And does it work? Try to debug the commands with `-vvv` switches to the `ssh`. It will show you what is actually executed and passed to each other shell.

Comment: Thanks for the response! 1. The multiple -t were added as the manual of ssh stated "Multiple -t options force tty allocation". 2. echo proc dies and kills the sudo su - that's why i used that construction, 3. i need to have an interactive shell as root so sudo != sudo su

Comment: `sudo -i` is what you need. If you close the stdin for the `sudo`, it obviously ends.

Comment: just tried it and without the `cat` construction it kills the connection, thanks.